# CoreData (MagicalRecord) returning the wrong values

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, magicalrecord

To save the primary animal in a zoo I do this:

```
-(void)makePrimary:(Animal*)animal

Zoo *currentZoo = [Zoo findFirstByAttribute:@"zooId" withValue:self.currentZooId];
currentZoo.primaryAnimalId = animal.animalId;

[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
DLog(@"primaryAnimalId: %d", currentZoo.primaryAnimalId.intValue); //logs "3"

}
```

After doing this, the primaryAnimalId for currentZoo logs as 3. I am using the Firefox SQLite Manager to verify this. ZPRIMARYANIMALID is 3 there as well.

Now, I navigate to a different section of the app, where I need to display the primary animal. So I do this:

```
-(Animal*)getPrimaryAnimalForCurrentZoo
{

    Zoo *currentZoo = [Zoo findFirstByAttribute:@"zooId" withValue:self.currentZooId];
    DLog(@"primaryAnimalId: %d", currentZoo.primaryAnimalId.intValue); //logs 2
    Animal *primaryAnimal = [Animal MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"animalId" withValue:currentZoo.primaryAnimalId];

    return primaryAnimal;

}
```

Much to my chagrin, I get "2" for the primaryAnimalId, and thus the wrong animal is returned. "2" is the previous value of the animal before I change it via `makePrimary:`. currentZooId is 0 in both methods.

What I don't understand is how I can get the wrong value back from Core Data when I can clearly see the correct value currently in the database (in SQLite Manager). How is this possible and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update self.currentZooId to reflect your changes?

---

Update:
So, you're asking for the first record in your data set here. The thing is,you're not specifying an order. That is, findFirst just asks the data store for all, and then just returns the first in the list (have a look at the code for more specifics). Since that list can be in any order, you're going to get whatever the data store gives you in at particular instance. What you want to do is add a sort parameter to findFirst to make sure you always get the item you expect. Look at the headers to find the correct firstFirst method with a sort parameter.

Comment: Yes, it has a value of 0 in both methods.